# BleachBit for all users

Tags: bleachbit, multiple-users

New to Linux, but learning fast. I have set up a user "thekids" for the kids. When I run BleachBit (BB) to clean up my user-stuff before a Clonezilla image backup, I'd like some way for it to also clean up the kids area too?

I don't want to add them to the sudo list just so BB can run as root in their area. Giving them sudo access would break the idea behind giving them their own isolated area.

Comment: Possibly the easiest way is that you log in as "thekids" and run BleachBit from there.

Comment: I don't really see how useful that program is for user accounts, the apt cache and old kernel removal is fine tho.

Answer (score 0):

Run sudo from your account, and from the kids account run with normal privileges.

BleachBit on Linux uses sudo for shared items such as apt,  system logs, and localizations.

Comment: OK, thanks, I wasn't sure how it all worked, but that sounds exactly the end result I am after.